# Is it possible to call diffrent instances from static util

Tags: java, static, polymorphism

Update: I rewrite my question with more details.

Class Disk is a third party with long init time so I want to create it only once as a static member. Since I can't change it I want to wrap it with my own logic as a utility class.

Lets say I have created utilities:

```
class DiskUtilC {
   static Disk disk = new Disk("c:\\");
   
   List static searchFile(String name) {
       return soSomething(disk.search(name)); 
   }

   ...many more static methods ...
}
```

```
class DiskUtilD {
   static Disk disk = new Disk("d:\\");
   
   List static searchFile(String name) {
       return soSomething(disk.search(name)); 
   }
   
   ...many more static methods ...
}
```

Since both classes use the same static method I want move them all to a common location but keep the same usage i.e.

```
DiskUtilC.searchFile("xxx"); 
DiskUtilD.searchFile("xxx");
```

It's not possible to use polymorphism with static I'm not sure if it is possible.

I know that I can always do something like this DiskUtil.getInstance("c").searchFile("xxx") but it's too cumbersome. Is there a way to do it like I demonstrated above?

Comment: If you want to use the class in a non-static way, why is it static in the first place?

Comment: I do want to use it in a static way. i.e. DiskUtilC.searchFile("xxx); I just don't want to duplicate the methods also for DiskUtilD utility.

Comment: So `DiskUtilC` is not an instance, it's another class entirely that inherits from `DiskUtil`?

Comment: yes, I want two classes DiskUtilC and DiskUtilD with the same static methods but use different instances.

Comment: Different instances of what? Can you please explain what you mean? You mean a different `disk`s?

Comment: Even after seeing your update I'm not sure I see why you want this to be static. It seems to me like the textbook example of the need to instantiate a `DiskUtil` which should have a constructor that accepts a `Disk` (or even just a string to pass to the `Disk` constructor itself). In other words, the language doesn't accommodate for your use case because, basically, you're using the wrong solution for the problem. Unless you can make a strong case for why you want this to work with static methods.

Comment: Class Disk is a third party with expensive init time so I want to create it only once as a static member.

I want to warp it with my own logic. How do you suggest I can do it?

Comment: Considering that `static Disk disk = new Disk("c:\\");` requires you to pass in the drive as a parameter to `Disk`'s constructor, I don't see any way to avoid instantiating two `Disk`s (one for C and one for D) anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any benefit to defining two classes DiskUtilC and DiskUtilD with identical code and different static fields - one may edited out of step with the other.

If the handling logic for C+D drives is identical (that is they don't need different `soSomething` implementations) you could declare one DiskUtil class with 2 static fields for C and D drives and instance methods such as `getName` / `searchFile`. Example:

```
class DiskUtil {
   static final DiskUtil C = new DiskUtil("c:\\");
   static final DiskUtil D = new DiskUtil("d:\\");
   
   private final Disk disk;
   private DiskUtil(String root) {
       disk = new Disk(root)
   }
   
   void getName() {
       return disk.name();   
   }

   List searchFile(String name) {
    return soSomething(disk.search(name)); 
   }
   
   ...many more... (not-static methods)
}
```

Then the usage is via DiskUtil:

```
DiskUtil.C.searchFile("xxx"); 
DiskUtil.D.searchFile("xxx");
```

But it's probably better to use `DiskUtil.getInstance("c")` or similar so you can make `getInstance` initialise any drives as necessary on demand on first use rather than hardwire C/D only. An example on demand load can also setup say `C()` to simplify typing:

```
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String,DiskUtil> DISKS = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private static DiskUtil getInstance(String drive) {
    return DISKS.computeIfAbsent(drive.toLowerCase(), letter -> new DiskUtil(letter+":\\"));
}
// Handy access to C:
static DiskUtil C() { return getInstance("C"); }
```

Comment: Yes this is equivalent to my example DiskUtil.getInstance("c").searchFile("xxx") 
You just replaced getInstance("c") with C which is a bit more elegant :)

Comment: You could of course add `static ConcurrentHashMap<String,DiskUtil> DISKS = new ...` and make `getInstance(String drive)` call `DISKS.computeIfAbsent(drive, letter -> new DiskUtil(letter+":\\")`